# ASP.NET Core page returns before signin

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm working on a .NET Core 1.1 ASP.NET app with cookies authentication and I noticed something a bit weird. I'm noticing that when I hit my `Login` page it says that I'm not authenticated even if though that's the only thing the action does. If I refresh the page or navigate to another page I'm authenticated. It almost seems as if the view is returned before the async sign in happens.

**Controller Method**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login()
{
        ClaimsPrincipal userPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(/*Setup the principal*/);

        await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("Cookie", userPrincipal, new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5),
            IsPersistent = false,
            AllowRefresh = false
        });

    return View();
}
```

**View**

```
@if (this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true)
{
    <span>You're authenticated!</span>
}
else
{
    <span>You're not authenticated.</span>
}
```

If I navigate to `/Controller/Login` I get that I'm not authenticated, but if I go to another view with the same code it will then say I'm authenticated. This isn't a big issue but I'm worried I may have set something up incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design. You must perform a redirect, such as `RedirectToAction`, after the call to `SignInAsync` since the User object will not be reconstructed until the next request to the server.

Comment: Interesting, thanks! Is there any documentation about this?

Comment: I don't have any link to official documentation for it, but it just makes perfect sense since User.Identity is for the current request and SignInAsync modifies the response so that the newly constructed cookie will be sent with the next request.